# Adding tabs dynamically in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm trying to dynamically create `Tab`s in QML. The code below is a simple example of what I want to do.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow{
    id:win

    TabView{
        id:tb
        anchors.fill:parent

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked:tb.loadTab()
        }

        Component{
            id:viewComp
            Rectangle{
                anchors.fill:parent
                color:"black"
            }
        }

        function loadTab(){
            var t=addTab("x",viewComp)
            t.item.color="blue" //line 20
        }
    }
}
```

Addition of the first `Tab` works as expected. However, after that any other `Tab` added triggers the error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of null`.

I tried to access the `Tab`with `getTab()` to change the color, but I get the same error. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got around and tried to fix this and was successful. Decided to post as an answer in case someone stumbles on this from google and has a similar problem.

The solution was to set the `currentIndex` to the new `Tab` and then set properties of the `Tab`. This means that the function `loadTab()` looks like this:

```
loadTab(){
    var c_tab=currentIndex
    var t=tb.addTab("x",viewComp)
    currentIndex=count-1
    t.item.color="blue" 
    currentIndex=c_tab
}
```

This works nicely.

Comment: It should also be noted that `Tab` inherits from `Loader`: the component is lazily initialized. Setting the index force the `Loader ` to load the component as it becomes visible. Another solution is to set `active: true` to force loading even if the `Tab` is not visible i.e. the `currentIndex` is not set to the newly created `Tab`.

Answer (score 0):

better solution:

```
loadTab(){
    var c_tab=currentIndex
    var t=tb.addTab("x",viewComp)
    t.active = true;// real loading
    t.item.color="blue" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if there is a way to enforce the construction of QML items. In onCompleted of the main window I am looping through all children recursively, and check if the factorySetting property is true. If so, I set it disabled (to be enabled by a password). However, I have nested TabViews, and it seems that until a Tab is not exposed, it is not constructed and the length of its children is zero, so that I can not recursively look into them. I could look for the QML object type and if it is Tab_QMLTYPE_xxxx then call object.active=1; on it. However, I have some customized Tabs which are defined for example in Adc.qml, and these objects are therefore named as Adc_QMLTYPE_xxx. Any proposals?

Comment: Answering my own question: I check if the element has an 'active' property, and I try to set it to true, hoping that with some other QML objects it will not cause  a problem.     if("active" in obj)  { try { obj.active = true; } catch (err) {} }